# Big and/or open source games based on SlimDX

Tags: c#, slimdx

Are there any major titles or open source games based on SlimDX framework out there? I understand that it's pretty much just a wrapper on top of DirectX, but it would still be interesting to see it used in a mature environment.

I am looking for some kind of story behind games as well: some hindsight on how the framework was chosen, what the pitfalls were, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found on the official website this:

SlimDX is currently rock solid, covers just about every multimedia API provided by Microsoft, and is stable enough to be used by commercial projects and companies, including several AAA game studios.

Several companies and products using SlimDX:

- Spiderman: Web of Shadows
- Zipper Interactive
- LizardTech
- Star Wars: The Force Unleashed

PD:   Vote up just for letting me know about this framework :)

Comment: I was looking for some story as well. Not just the end result.

Comment: Unfortunately you're probably not likely to get the 'story' out of the commercial game developers -- I do know that Zipper was using it for their tools though, as I know the tools developers.

Comment: Well like, the Force Unleashed was on consoles too, right? -- Like the Wii -- was it really used in the game or just for tooling, or just for the PC port, or what? -- I don't see any other details than the names.  Not super helpful. (Not a criticism of your answer, but of the homepage...)

Answer (score 5):

[AI War](http://www.arcengames.com/aiwar_features.php) used SlimDX for a while, until they switched over to Unity. Chris's original blog post on choosing the platform is [here](http://christophermpark.blogspot.com/2009/06/choosing-directx-platform-in-c.html), and his follow up on the API after he switched to Unity is [here](http://christophermpark.blogspot.com/2010/10/in-support-of-slimdx.html).

(N.B. I am one of the SlimDX developers)

Comment: in 2nd blog post that you linked he says he switched to unity3d

Comment: @JoshPetrie -- can you comment on The Force Unleashed? -- It was a console game for several consoles, including the Wii, right? -- Why would a Wii game use a DirectX wrapper library? -- Or was it only used in the Windows port of the game? -- or by the tooling team (and not in the actual game), etc? -- Any more details would be interesting to know.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 As I recall, we thought that they used it in their Windows installer or launcher. It would have been impractical to use it for the game itself, obviously. If it wasn't in the launcher it was probably for internal tools.